# Not able to get month from current date

Tags: vb.net, date

Am trying to extract month from the current date but in vain. I am using the code:

```
    Format(Today.Date, "mmmm")
```

However when I try to run it to display month like January it instead displays 00. I thought that this would work but it isn't. What can I do to get the month from current date in vb.net using a simple approach like a single function?

Comment: Lower case m is for minutes, uppercase M is for month.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you. I had actually figured it out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try This :

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM")
```

Check out [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for detailed date formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    MonthName(Now.Date.Month(),true)
```

Comment: set false if you want the full name of month.

Answer (score 0):

msdn: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
Format(Today.Date, "MMMM")
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. This works best for me although there may be other ways

Answer (score 0):

EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW()) , getting month of current date